# gpu utilization question( nvidia-smi prints that I am using gpu but task manager shows I am not using gpu )

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, gpu

I am running tensorflow program and just curious why nvidia-smi shows that I am using gpu but
why task manager shows I am not using a gpu.

I was running same tensorflow code in my computer(windows 10) and in server(ubuntu 16.04).
I figured out the program runs fast in server and I was curious what makes it faster.
gpu memories were more utilized in my computer than in server when I saw the result of nvidia-smi.
and I found that nvidia-smi prints that prgram is using a gpu but task manager prints the program is not using a gpu!

```
(base) PS C:\Users\82102> nvidia-smi
Wed Sep 11 19:35:47 2019
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.86       Driver Version: 430.86       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070   WDDM  | 00000000:23:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 55%   69C    P2   163W / 175W |   7745MiB /  8192MiB |     38%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

task manager shows the python program does not use gpu! ( I cannot upload images yet )

In server, the program is using gpu too.

```
[0] TITAN Xp         | 84'C,  66 % |  4516 / 12192 MB | yoonah(4505M)
[1] TITAN Xp         | 31'C,   0 % |   158 / 12196 MB | yoonah(147M)
```

why task manager shows the program is not using gpu? really curious

Answer (score 0):

Please try enabling the GPU configurations and WDDM for windows, below links can help you.

```
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/monitor-gpu-usage-iusing-task-manager
https://www.howtogeek.com/351073/how-to-monitor-gpu-usage-in-the-windows-task-manager
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but I already did your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Above the graphs displayed under the GPU section in Task Manager, there are options for reporting. If you select "Compute" graphs you can see usage there.